# Attachments and Images in email body using Eden Imap Library

Tags: php, email, imap, laravel-5.6, eden

I'm using this library in my project and its working perfect if there no image in the email or in attachment to get getUniqueEmails($email = $imap->getUniqueEmails(emailuid, true);) but if there is any attachment or image in the body it didn't return anything, error is with getting the objects attached in the body or attachment. Please help me out to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.